# I need link to backand SDK for android

Tags: android, sdk, backand

I have created android app and I am using backand.com so I have been looking for backand sdk for android.

If anyone have any idea about it than please help.

Comment: Why did you choose backand if you can't find a client?

Answer (score 1):

Backand is designed as a REST API with a focus on AngularJS so there is an javascript / AngularJS SDK, but I'm not aware of any other SDKs.

You may want to look at other BaaS providers if a REST API doesn't do what you're wanting.